# not able to start uwsgi as a service in docker

Tags: docker, uwsgi

1)I have copied my demo.ini file inside /etc/uwsgi/app-enabled/demo.ini

2)I have installed the package  apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python

3)Added the plugins= python in demi.ini file
now when i hit the command sudo service uwsgi status it shows output which?

```
FROM base_image 
RUN apt-get -y install uwsgi 
COPY workspace /home/nt/workspace 
RUN ln -s /home/nt/workspace/backend.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/backend.conf 
RUN ln -s /home/nt/workspace/nti-backend/environment/development.ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/ 
RUN pip install -r /home/nt/workspace/nti-backend/requirements.txt 
ENTRYPOINT sh /home/nt/workspace/startup.sh && /bin/bash
```

Comment: add your Dockerfile, your `docker run` command

Comment: FROM base_image
RUN apt-get -y install  uwsgi
COPY workspace /home/nt/workspace
RUN ln -s /home/nt/workspace/backend.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/backend.conf
RUN ln -s /home/nt/workspace/nti-backend/environment/development.ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/
RUN pip install -r /home/nt/workspace/nti-backend/requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT sh /home/nt/workspace/startup.sh && /bin/bash

Comment: In base image i have installed nginx , memcached ,redis-server some basic requirement for my project.                                                                                                        In startup.sh i have just started all this services @user2915097

Comment: @GauravKumar please format question properly, so we can read it and help you. What is in `startup.sh`, show the actual code? Is there any errors? Could you add the output of commands?

Comment: startup.sh file contains                                                                                       1)sudo service nginx restart                                                                                        2)sudo service redis-server restart                                                                            3)sudo service memcached restart @Зелёный

Comment: what you have in startup.sh is correct for a VM, not for a container, you should have something like `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` for nginx, and so, better use supervisor if you want to start several processess, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/

Comment: but all of the services in startup.sh are running  fine. My issue is with running uwsgi as service inside container

Comment: It's not a good pattern to start several processes in one container, so @Зелёный is right. Try to separate nginx, application server (uwsgi + python) and database server (redis as I understand).
Also it's not clear how you're starting the uwsgi up? I guess you need to start it in your startup.sh like nginx or redis?

Comment: @GauravKumar can you tell me the state of your problem? Do you any further help? I can send you docker-compose configurations if you need.